# Case insensitive search using Mongo's bson.M{}

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to get my mongo query to perform a partial and case insensitive match. I am currently doing this

```
bson.M{"$regex": primitive.Regex{Pattern: regexp.QuoteMeta(school), Options: "i"}
```

school is of type `interface` so I am getting this error -

```
Cannot use school (variable of type interface{}) as string value in argument to regexp.QuoteMeta
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use a `string` value, not an `interface{}`. E.g. if you want to find results containing `"foo"`, this is valid: `primitive.Regex{Pattern: regexp.QuoteMeta("foo"), Options: "i"}`

Comment: It has to be an interface.

Comment: Why does it have to be an `interface{}`?

Comment: @icza Let's assume I decide not to use `primitive.Regex`, is there an alternative that allows me use `school` as an interface.

Comment: @icza why it has to be an interface is because school can be  string, bool,  etc

Comment: @icza I used `type assertion`. Thanks

Comment: If it's a `bool`, then regexp doesn't make any sense, only if you have a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

In a Golang application I developed, I was able to got the data via MongoDb as follows.

```
bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$regex": term, "$options": "i"}}
```

"name" is my field name.

"term" is word for searching.